# Jetpack Compose - How can add multiple modifier to a composable and is the order important?

Tags: android-jetpack, composable

I wanted to know how we can add multiple modifier, for example adding background, padding and more to an android jetpack composable?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's really simple;
You can chain multiple modifiers.

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.preferredHeight(500.dp).padding(100.dp)) {
Text("Hello")  }
```

And The order is important; Modifier elements to the left are applied before modifier elements to the right.

Comment: How can I chain `fillMaxSize` with `padding`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky

Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp).fillMaxWidth()) {
            Text(text = "hello")
            Text(text = name)
        }

Answer (score 0):

if you have to use two different modifier, you can simply use .then() function to add second modifier

For Example,
let's say you have a composable function in which we have passed a modifier as a parameter and inside that function we have a box which already have a modifier. so by using then modifier you can add the modifier which have been passed as a parameter

```
    @Composable
    fun myView(modifier: Modifier) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .background(Color.Black)
                .then(modifier)
        )

}
```

and yes order your in which you are adding modifiers matters